# let o = Object() cause an error in Realm Swift 3.0

Tags: realm, swift3

> [RealmSwiftObject defaultPropertyValues]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10b135cf0
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[RealmSwiftObject defaultPropertyValues]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10b135cf0'

Just one line code

let o = Object()

Xcode 8 beta 6, Realm Cocoa master #ec83637. Swift 3.

Comment: This seems a lot like something you should be [reporting to Realm's developers](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#filing-issues).

Comment: @bdash OK. I will. I know your name as you have helped me before.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not actually useful to create an instance of `Object` directly, since it's designed to be subclassed to create Realm models.
2. Realm still shouldn't be crashing and are tracking a fix in https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4005

Comment: That issue was created by myself as @bdash suggested. And I learned a lot from it.